# Spark SQL query with IN operator in CASE WHEN cannot be cast to SparkPlan

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to execute the test query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN (SELECT name FROM requiredProducts) THEN name END)
FROM myProducts
```

which throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation cannot be cast to
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan
```

I have a suggestion that *IN* operator can not be used in *CASE WHEN*. Is it really so? Spark documentation is silent about this.

Comment: Can you give your full sample code ?

Comment: In my experience, I've found that Spark doesn't handle all normal SQL queries. However, when redesigned to use the Spark SQL functions on top of DataFrames, they work - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *IN* operator using a subquery does not work in a projection regardless of whether it is contained in a *CASE WHEN*, it will only work in filters. It works fine if you specify values in the *IN* clause directly rather than using a subquery.

I am not sure how to generate the exact exception you got above, but when I attempt to run a similar query in Spark Scala, it returns a more descriptive error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in a Filter: Project [CASE WHEN agi_label#5 IN (list#96 []) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CASE WHEN (agi_label IN (listquery())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END#97]
```

I have run into this issue in the past. Your best bet is probably to restructure it to use a left join to `requiredProducts` and then check for a null in the case statement. For example, something like this might work:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN rp.name is not null THEN mp.name END)
FROM myProducts mp 
  LEFT JOIN requiredProducts rp ON mp.name = rp.name
```